# Python: removing objects form lists based on object attribute

Tags: python, django

I have a list of python objects and I'd like to remove duplicates in the list based on the time value.
For example:

```
class MyClass(object):

    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    stat_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.label)
```

My list may have several instances of MyClass with the same label but different stat_times.
I'd like to trim the list and have only one instance of the label with the latest stat_time.

```
>>> my_list
[MyClass: xxx, MyClass: yyy, MyClass: yyy, MyClass: zzz]
```

I'd like to end up with:

```
>>> my_list
[MyClass: xxx, MyClass: yyy, MyClass: zzz]
```

Here my_list should only contain one instance of MyClass with the 'yyy' label with the latest stat_time.

I hope I have made that clear.
Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a Django question?

Comment: I haven't used Django but I imagine it would be easier to make sure copies aren't added in the first place instead of sanitizing the list afterwards.

Comment: Is the order of items important in your list?

Comment: What attempts have you made and what's wrong with them?

Comment: Do you want to filter on `__unicode__` or `stat_time`? As your Q currently stands, it's a bit hard to understand.

Comment: BTW: You should return `unicode(self.label)`, not `str(self.label)` in the `__unicode__` method. You may run into decoding errors otherwise.

Comment: Hi. Yes, this is a Django environment (in fact my Class should read class MyClass(models.Model). The order of the items are not important just as long as I have a unique list with the latest stat_time. I have tried using groupby from itertools but that will only group them by name. I then still need to filter them on the latest stat_time.

Comment: I need to filter on both the label name AND the stat_time, so I get a unique label with the latest stat_time.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is to create a `dict` mapping values of `label` to `MyClass` instances.  You would add each the elements of your list to this `dict`, but only keep the wanted values.

```
aDict = dict()
for element in myList:
    s = element.label
    if s not in aDict: # the key is not used yet
        aDict[s] = element
    else:
        aDict[s] = max(aDict[s], element, key = lambda x: x.stat_time)
myList = list(aDict.items()) # iteritems() in Python 2
```

The `lambda` expression passed into `max` tells Python which value to compare when computing the max.

Comment: You can rewrite the max clause like `element if element[s].stat_time > aDict[s].stat_time else aDict[s]` so that it reads almost like plain English.

Comment: Thanks, however will this not just add the first element encountered?

Comment: @9000 Good suggestion, I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you should filter your object based on `__unicode__()`, but here is how I would have done it.

```
unique_objs = []

for o in my_list:
    if (o.__unicode__(), o.stat_time) in unique_objs:
        continue
    new_list.append(o)
    unique_objs.append(tuple(o.__unicode__(), o.stat_time))
```

Comment: Thanks,. However, that will only get me a unique list of objects based on the name - I need to have a unique list based on name AND latest time for stat_time.

Comment: @KevinSheahan I changed the answer. Does this suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks. unique_objs.add can only take one argument, and there is no comparison for the latest time but the solution will probably look something like this.

Comment: @KevinSheahan I updated the answer, it should work now